# Как исправить на сайте ошибки валидации wc3?

Tags: css, css3, валидация

На сайте есть 3 ошибки валидации **WC3** - как их исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. ```
   *{
           margin:0px;padding:0px;
           border:0px;
           outline-style:none;
           -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
           -moz-text-size-adjust:none;
           -ms-text-size-adjust:none;
           text-size-adjust:none;
           box-sizing:border-box;
           -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
           -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
           -webkit-appearance:none;
       }
   ```
2. ```
   a:hover span.like svg path,
   a:hover span.comment svg path{
       fill:#252525;
   }
   ```

В статичном состоянии решается заменой **css** свойства на атрибут тега `html`. А как быть с ховер-состоянием?

3. ```
   .flipster--coverflow .flipster__item__content {
       transform-origin: 50% 100%;
       box-reflect: below 0 -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.05, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12)),
    color-stop(0.2, transparent));
   -webkit-box-reflect: below 0 -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.05, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12)),
    color-stop(0.2, transparent));
   }
   ```

Comment: 1. Не использовать вендорные префиксы либо забить на ошибки. 2. Готовить 2 картинки svg? 3. Не использовать вендорные префиксы либо забить на ошибки.

Comment: 1) Похоже на баг валидатора, можно изменить `text-size-adjust` на `100%`; 2) У меня валидатор никаких ошибок здесь не пишет, включите SVG в опциях валидатора; 3) Свойства `box-reflect` не существует, удалите его

Comment: @DaemonHK в валидаторе вендорные префиксы не считаются ошибками

Comment: @andreymal ТС не показал первую ошибку, поэтому не понятно что там и чего.

Comment: @DaemonHK как это не показал, CSS есть, скриншот ошибки есть

Comment: @andreymal извиняюсь, затупил

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78914/discussion-between-daemonhk-and-andreymal).

Comment: 1 совет не помог - ставил и `text-size-adjust:auto` и `text-size-adjust:100%`, результат ошибки тот же;
2 - включил svg в опциях - ошибка ушла, вопрос снимается
3 - @andreymal есть такое свойство и удалить просто нельзя - вики ссылка https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-box-reflect
вот здесь есть фидл рабочий кроссбраузерный https://codepen.io/jonathan/pen/pgioE, но я не могу понять параметры по которым строится свойство

Comment: @Вася вы дали ссылку на свойство `-webkit-box-reflect` — это свойство существует, но только в хроме. А вот свойства `box-reflect` не существует нигде, удалите его